# Why put Cart in MaskedWalletRequest?

Tags: android-pay

In the docs, when building the `MaskedWalletRequest` they say:

> At this point, you won't have the user's chosen shipping address, so
>   you'll need to create an estimate of the shipping costs and tax. If
>   you set the shopping cart as shown below (highly recommended), make
>   sure the cart total matches the sum of the line items added to the
>   cart.

[link](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/tutorial#create_a_masked_wallet_request)

Later when I create my `FullWalletRequest` I have to pass in a `Cart`*. So why would I want to add a `Cart` to my `MaskedWalletRequest`? Why is it "highly recommended"?

*If I don't pass in a `Cart` I'll get `WalletConstants.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_PARAMETERS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Android Pay documentation states, Google highly recommends setting the shopping cart in the Masked Wallet request. Having additional line item information at this point of the transaction greatly increases Google's fraud detection capabilities, and also lets you provide more detailed purchase information to your users.

At this point, you won't have the user's chosen shipping address from Android Pay, so you must create an estimate of the shipping costs and tax.